# Highcharts, show total data as a live stream

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

What I am trying to do is quite interesting but I am struggling to proceed with my thought:

**What I have done:**

I have a CSV file containing 100 datasets. These datasets are points which I plot on the Y-axis.

All the 100 points are plotting as expected on the HighCharts graph as I show you in the following figure:

[image: Highchart's data of 100 points]

**Code:**

The following is the code I used to get the above result:

```js
$.get('abc.csv', function(data) {
    var lines = []
    lines = data.split('\n');
    var ppgData=[];

    $.each(lines, function(ppgNo, ppgContent) {
        if (ppgNo >= 0) {
            ppgData[ppgNo - 0] = parseFloat(ppgContent.substring(ppgContent.lastIndexOf(',') + 1));
        }
    });

    Highcharts.chart('ppg', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'ECG Data'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            crosshair: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'ECG Peaks'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enable: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: '',
            lineWidth: 1,
            data: ppgData,
            animation: {
                duration: 15000
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

**What I want to achieve:**

1. I want to show only the first 10 points on the graph.
2. I want to show the other data in 10 10 patches but in the same graph by removing the last 10 plots until I reach all the 100 points.

Is this possible in Highcharts using JavaScript? If so then please suggest how I might do so?

Any help is really appreciated thanks.

Here is the working JS fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/3vj2afnt/

Comment: Don't understand your question well. Can you photoshop the graph to show what you expect?

Comment: give me few minutes time, I'll give u the idea f what exactly do i want

Comment: Is it different from just updating the data? https://www.highcharts.com/demo/chart-update

Comment: @moshfeu it's a little different . All the data is already there . It just have to be smooth

Comment: It looks like highchart knows how to do it smoothly.. Anyway, to make it faster, can you show the format of the csv? Or, if you can create a working example (something with jsbin, jsfiddle, codepen etc.) so I could modify it to the wanted behaviour (and tell you about that, of course :) )

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/3vj2afnt/

here I created a fiddle . @MoshFeu

Comment: I'm on it :) I'll update you

Comment: [Let's continue in a chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198511/https-stackoverflow-com-q-57569943-863110)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of but works.

1. Use `scrollablePlotArea` option to let the chart to be scrollable.
2. Wrap the chart with a `div` with `overflow: hidden` to hide the scrollbar.
3. Run a script to do the scroll animation

```js
var xValues = [];
xValues = [1, 4, 3, 9, 3, 4, 4, 6, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 6, 7, 3, 6, 7, 4, 7, 4, 7, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 4, 6, 6, 7, 3, 6, 7, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 9, 8, 4, 6, 2, 1, 5, 8, 5, 8, 2, 6, 3, 8, 4, 7, 3, 6, 1, 5, 8, 0, 2, 4, 7, 5, 8, 3, 7, 9, 3, 7];

const drawAnimationDuration = 5000;

Highcharts.chart('ppg', {
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    // use that option to let the rest of the chart be scrollable. Play with the "minWidth" value if you need
    scrollablePlotArea: {
      minWidth: 800,
      scrollPositionX: 0
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'ECG Data'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    crosshair: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Peaks'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    enable: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: '',
    lineWidth: 2,
    data: xValues,
    animation: {
      duration: drawAnimationDuration
    }
  }]
});

// wait for the chart to done the animation.
// play with the second parameter (duration) of the `.animate` function (currently is 10000) to accelerate or slow down. For more info: https://api.jquery.com/animate/#duration
setTimeout(() => {
  $('.highcharts-scrolling').animate({
    scrollLeft: $('.highcharts-container').width()
  }, 10000, 'linear');
}, drawAnimationDuration)
```

```css
#ppg {
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 320px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.ppg-wrapper {
  /* hide the child's scrollbar */
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ppg-wrapper">
  <div id="ppg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this approach, no.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is to show the data in batches of 10 points.

I can think of 2 ways of doing this. The first one is to add the points on each batch and the second one is to change the min/max properties.

One way will expand the chart horizontally, and the other will just pop the lines inside the chart. I don't know what do you exactly want so here you have both ways:

**min/max: https://jsfiddle.net/xaj42sLp/**

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    data.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
}
let max = 10;
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: max
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
                label: {
                enabled: false
            },
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
});
function nextUpdate() {
    max+= 10;
    chart.xAxis[0].update({
        max: max
    });
    if (max < data.length) {
            setTimeout(nextUpdate, 1000);
    }
}
setTimeout(nextUpdate, 1000);
```

**Series points: https://jsfiddle.net/xaj42sLp/1/**

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    data.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
}
let max = 10;
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: data.length
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
                label: {
                enabled: false
            },
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: data.slice(0, max)
    }]
});
function nextUpdate() {
    // Avoid setData for performance reasons
    for (var i = max; i < max+10; i++) {
        chart.series[0].addPoint(data[i]);
    }
    max+= 10;
    if (max < data.length) {
            setTimeout(nextUpdate, 1000);
    }
}
setTimeout(nextUpdate, 1000);
```

NOTE: Highcharts has a lot of animation options. You can check [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/) the API and search for `animation` keyword. With the `setTimeout` above and the animation options you can fine-tune animations pretty well.

EDIT: Got your needings. Here's a solution:

**Linear live: https://jsfiddle.net/aks7vu1w/**

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            animation: {
            duration: 500,
            easing: function(t) {return t;}
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 9
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
                label: {
                enabled: false
            },
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: []
    }]
});
let pointCount = 0;
function nextPoint() {
    let completed = false;
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(Math.max(pointCount-9, 0), pointCount < 10 ? 9 : pointCount);
    chart.series[0].addPoint([pointCount, Math.floor(Math.random()*10)], true, pointCount >= 10);
    pointCount++;
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Needed so animations don't overlap 
        requestAnimationFrame(nextPoint);
    }, 500);
}
nextPoint();
```

Comment: What you did is very good. but it is not smooth enough. although I want to show the data as a live stream. like ECG data in monitor. I hope you understand

Comment: as per your chart, I want that at one point when the data reach the 10 points the 0 value data should be removed one by one so it should look like data flowing rather thank data look conjusted in one area.

Comment: Something like that? https://www.highcharts.com/demo/?example=dynamic-update&theme=default

Comment: Yes sure like this but little faster and smooth. Can u check my fiddle

Comment: If you update my fiddle that would be a great help. I mentioned it in my question

Comment: Dear @MoshFeu , Can you please check my Fiddle

Comment: Hey @MoshFeu, I think only you could solve my problem. please check my fiddle and suggest me the changes that I have to do.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález your flow is exactly what I needed but its coming of random data. My data is already mentioned. I want the same flow with my data.

Comment: @AbnitChauhan Well, you can read the code, understand what is happening and implement your code. Stackoverflow people is not here to do your homework, but to help you to code xD All the magic happens inside `nextPoint()`. There's an `addPoint` and a `setExtremes`. You just have to add a new point and adjust the extremes when needed.